# asp.net core <select> with tag-helpers, make a specif <option> tag be selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core, with .NET 6.

I have a view model:

```
class SomeModel {
 
    public int SelectedProjectId {get; set; } // This is the current project.
    // Some more properties.
 
}
```

My select:

```
 <select asp-for="ProjectId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(projects, nameof(Project.ProjectId), nameof(Project.Name)))"></select>
```

This works fine, but my problem is, the select is used to edit existing data, so how can I make sure the `option-tag` with the value of `SelectedProjectId` is selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the code you shared, try the following...

```
<select asp-for="ProjectId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(projects, nameof(Project.ProjectId), nameof(Project.Name), SomeModel.SelectedProjectId))"></select>
```

You add a third parameter to SelectList with the selected value.

Here is the reference of SelectList constructors:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-selectlist-ctor(system-collections-ienumerable-system-string-system-string-system-object)

Comment: Thanks! I should have changed my question a bit, since in my example 'SelectedProjectId' is not nullable, but it can be null (it's optional) would this also work if the value is null? (if I add an option like: <option>select a value</option>)?

Comment: I believe it can be done, with some custom code, create a 0 option with "Select a value" and default to 0 when null.

Comment: Thanks, yes, something like 'selectedProjectId ?? 0' and <option value=0>select a value</option would do :)